# Windows Phone Emulator - Hyper-v

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, hyper-v

I bought a dell inspiron 15 Special Edition Intel. I Installed Windows 8 Proffesional. I want to run Windows phone emulator in my Laptop.When I run the emulator its showed a  error Hyper v missing in order to activated hyper v we have make changes in BIOS config.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCcQi.jpg

I checked and my notebook support all things required to run Windows Phone Emulator.
I think that problem is with BIOS. I couldn't find a required option. I attached photos of my BIOS.

[BIOS Images](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=33c77df447c4c041&id=33C77DF447C4C041!2001&authkey=!AI07rWxI8rlZ8D8)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't yet seen this, check this out :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

Personally, I have problems with starting the emulator for the first time on the installed Win8 OS. And I saw somewhere a post from a guy saying that `installed antivirus` can be causing some troubles. I have AVG and I turned it off temporarly and guess what, it started. Next emulator starts don't require antivirus temporary deactivation.

Altough from the print screen, your issue might be other, see what you can do about the antivirus, maybe it will work...

Answer (score 0):

Did you install a hyper-v at all?

You could check it in `Control Panel->Program and Features->Turn Windows features on or off`

Comment: I thought hyper-v is installed with Windows.  
I don't have Hyper-V option in Control Panel->Program and Features->Turn Windows features on or off.

Comment: Are you sure you're using a 64-bit operating system?

Comment: I also have same problem